# Why do I have to call next twice to ignore the first row of a csv?

Tags: python, csv

I wanted to check if the first (non-header) cell of a csv is empty.
I'm using the basic csv library for this and I've gottrn to it work but I don't understand why I have to first call the next method and then assign the csv to a new variable via the next method.

I need to understand if I'm doing something wrong

Here's my code:

```
import csv

csv_file_path = "session0.csv"

def check_semester(csv_file_path):
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

#why is this line necessary since I will be assigning the "next-ed" csv to a variable
        next(csv_reader, None) 
        
        second_row = next(csv_reader, []) 
        
        # Check if the first data cell is empty
        if second_row[0] == '':
            return False  # If the first cell is empty, return False
            
    return True  #else return true

if check_semester(csv_file_path):
    print("there's data")
else:
    print("no data")
```

I already tried using only the "nexted" assignment but it doesn't work.

Comment: Suppose that you did **not** want to ignore the first row: how do you think you would do that?

Comment: Next twice to get the second row, next five times to get the fifth row. What is unclear about that?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with two calls of the `next` function is essentially reading two rows while ignoring the first one (i.e., the header row). The following program may demonstrate this more clearly:

```py
import csv
import io

stream = io.StringIO("""\
first_row,a,b
second_row,1,2
""")

csv_reader = csv.reader(stream)

first_row = next(csv_reader)
second_row = next(csv_reader)

print(first_row)
print(second_row)
```

```
['first_row', 'a', 'b']
['second_row', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be clearer/cleaner if you read the entire CSV into a list of rows as you can make assertions on the list as a whole.  If you want to get back specific errors (and helpful error messages), you can make assertions instead of returning True/False:

```py
HEADER = ["Student", "Final Grade"]


def check_csv(fname: str):
    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        rows = list(reader)

        assert len(rows) >= 2,    f"expected at least a header and one row of data"
        assert rows[0] == HEADER, f"wrong header:\n   got: {rows[0]}\n  want: {HEADER}"
```

You can call the function like:

```py
fname = "input1.csv"
try:
    check_csv(fname)
except AssertionError as e:
    print(f"{fname}: failed assertion: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{fname}: unexpected error evaluating CSV: {e}")
```

If input1.csv looked like,

```
Students,Final Grade
Alice,            93
Bobby,            82
Charlie,          87
```

you'd get the helpful error message:

```
input1.csv: failed assertion: wrong header:
   got: ['Students', 'Final Grade']
  want: ['Student', 'Final Grade']
```

With that list of rows, in check_csv(), you can then check individual rows/columns, like making sure the grade is a number (float or int):

```py
...
    ...
        ...
        assert len(rows) >= 2,    f"expected at least a header and one row of data"
        assert rows[0] == HEADER, f"wrong header:\n   got: {rows[0]}\n  want: {HEADER}"

        for i, row in enumerate(rows[1:], start=1):
            try:
                float(row[1])
            except ValueError as e:
                raise AssertionError(f"row {i}, Final Grade was not a number: {e}")
```

The loop starts with the 2nd row (first row of data), `row[1:]`, and enumerates to keep track of which row to report any error for (starting at "row 1", `start=1`).  The try-except block catches any ValueError from a bad float() conversion and passes that error along with some context (row number, column name) as an AssertionError to be caught in the try-except for check_csv().

Fixing the header, but adding a (bad) fourth row to the CSV:

```
Student,Final Grade
Alice,           93
Bobby,           82
Charlie,         87
Dana,            A+
```

Produces the error:

```
input1.csv: failed assertion: row 4, Final Grade was not a number: could not convert string to float: 'A+'
```

You can test multiple files and get specific errors for each:

```py
for fname in ["input1.csv", "input2.csv"]:
    try:
        check_csv(fname)
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(f"{fname}: failed assertion: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{fname}: unexpected error evaluating CSV: {e}")
```

```
input1.csv: failed assertion: row 4, Final Grade was not a number: could not convert string to float: 'A+'
input2.csv: unexpected error evaluating CSV: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input2.csv'
```

Asking check_csv() to open a non-existent file raises FileNotFoundError, which is caught by the generic `except Exception as e` clause.

You can make the loop halt at the first sign of trouble with a boolean flag for any kind of error:

```py
for fname in ["input1.csv", "input2.csv"]:
    error = False
    try:
        check_csv(fname)
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(f"{fname}: failed assertion: {e}")
        error = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{fname}: unexpected error evaluating CSV: {e}")
        error = True

    if error:
        quit()
```